# how to direct .htaccess to pick right js file while using react-router?

Tags: .htaccess, react-router

I'm using react-router with .htaccess and browserHistory. If I understand it correctly, .htaccess file redirects the url to index.html when user addressed url that is only available from front-end and not available from the server. I copied and pasted the .htaccess rule from https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md and basically it's like below:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

The problem is that it doesn't use right js file when user enters sub-route. Let say I have two files in var/www - index.html, bundle.js.

Inside of index.html,

```
<body>
    <div id="content" class="content-div"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js" ></script>
</body>
```

Inside of bundle.js,

```
render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={AppComponent}>
            <Route path="post" component={PostComponent}>
                <Route path=":postid" component={PostItemComponent}></Route>
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('content'));
```

It works okay at main page - example.com. But when I enter example.com/post/1, the browser shows me blank page because it tries to access example.com/post/bundle.js which is not there (I don't even have post folder under var/www).

I could temporarily fix the problem by creating var/www/post folder and place bundle.js file into the folder. But I don't think that's right way to do it. Can someone please guide me how I could fix it, so that it always uses var/www/bundle.js whichever sub-sites user enters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a root-relative path for your script tag:

```
<body>
  <div id="content" class="content-div"></div>
  <script src="/bundle.js" ></script>
</body>
```